# How to select rows with null values based on a list of values using IN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm stacked out with this:

I'm trying to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column IN(2, 3, 5, null)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column IN('wert','qw3e','dfg',null)
```

But IN not considers NULL values, then I tryed this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF (4 is null, some_column is null, some_column IN (4))
```

This query works fine for ONE value, but as you can see in the first queries I need to consider multiple values, how?

Think I need to make a function that receives a parameter to find:

```
function (param) 
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF (param is null, some_column is null, some_column IN (param))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you try the following method

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column IN('wert','qw3e','dfg') OR some_column IS NULL
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF (4,3,4 is null, some_column is null, some_column IN (4,3,4))` ???????? 4,3,4 is the parameter for the query

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column IS NULL OR some_column IN('wert','qw3e','dfg')
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF (4,3,4 is null, some_column is null, some_column IN (4,3,4))` ???????? 4,3,4 is the parameter for the query

Comment: You provided two examples, but here you have for the other one, it's very much the same, just the IN() is different:


SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column IS NULL OR some_column IN(2, 3, 4)

Answer (score 2):

Two others have already answered, but there isn't an explanation as to why `IN(2, 3, 5, null)` doesn't return rows that have NULLs. That's because NULL is a special value, it does not equal anything. NULL = NULL essentially evaluates to False.

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NULL=NULL;
```

would return an empty result but

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NULL IS NULL;
```

wouuld return all the rows in your table. Thus the comparision for null values in your rows with the NULL in the IN array fails. So you need

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column 
 IN('wert','qw3e','dfg') OR some_column IS NULL
```

Comment: I think (and that how I did the answer) it's better to have the IS NULL before the IN() in that OR condition.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE IF (4,3,4 is null, some_column is null, some_column IN (4,3,4))` ???????? 4,3,4 is the parameter for the query, You cannot do `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column 
 IN('wert','qw3e','dfg') OR some_column IS 'wert','qw3e','dfg'`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @jakubwrona I think the query optimizer will be smart enough to change their positions based on the data (provided it has been indexed. If it hasn't been index, will not make a difference)

Comment: " I need to consider multiple values " and `some_colum IS NULL` is selecting the rows that has some_column NULL, really your query may be `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column 
 IN('wert','qw3e','dfg',null) OR some_column IS 'wert','qw3e','dfg',null` but you know you cannot do `some_column IS 'wert','qw3e','dfg',null`

Comment: You are still not being very clear. Why don't you post some sample data. and also show the desired result